# using stationary solution as the initial conditions in time dependent model

Tags: comsol

Is there a way to use the stationary solution obtained in Comsol 4.2 as the initial conditions in a time dependent model? I want to conduct a simulation to find a solution (u) and its first derivative (ux) using a 3D stationary model. Save this information to a file. Then use this file to provide the initial conditions in time dependent model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for COMSOL 5.2, but should be similar for 4.2:

1. Create the stationary study. The "Values for dependent values" in study step settings should be set to the default ("Physics-controlled" in 5.2). This will use the initial conditions you specified in your physics setting (usually 0 is used in the physics settings).
2. Create the time-dependent step or study. Set initial conditions in the physics to the appropriate dependent model variable names rather than the default 0. Set "Values for dependent variables" in study step settings to User Controlled...Solution...Your Stationary Study.
3. Solve the stationary study then the time dependent study. If you have both as steps in the same study, then solve that study.

Comment: Hi ! Do you also know how to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550076/simulation-of-effect-of-heated-resistance-on-temperature-distribution-in-laminar?noredirect=1#comment74163876_43550076